# Need to create a custom class in JAVA

Tags: java, class

I want to create a custom class object in JAVA and i created but it is showing an error...doesn't know why this error occurring, please help me coz i'm starting to learn JAVA earlier...

```
  class main {

    class student {
        public int rollno;
        public String name;
        public int marks;

        public void accept() {
            rollno = 1;
            name = "Pawan Mall";
            marks = 100;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.println(rollno);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(marks);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        student s = new student();
        s.accept();
        s.display();
    }

}
```

It was occurring at the time of compile 
that is the error which i faced while i compile the code :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\student.java:28: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
student s = new student();
            ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please indent your code, what is the error?

Comment: What is the error?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: When asking a question please indicate when you see the error (when you try to compile your code?, when you run it?) and the text of the error. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, that you got so many downvotes on your first question. You should use an IDE (like NetBeans) it will highlight your code and also tell you why it doesn't work often.

Comment: Significant improvement on the question noted

Comment: Pawan: the changes you made to your question made it much easier for people to help you, good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `student` class is *nested* inside the `main` class. As you haven't declared it as `static`, it is therefore an `inner` class. [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) says that:

*An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass.*

Since that is exactly what you are trying to do, it fails.

Your `student` class needs to be static, so you can instantiate it in a static context.

```
class main {

    static class student {
        public int rollno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the instance of student using main class reference like this

```
main m = new main();

student s= m.new student();
```

Answer (score -1):

The first char of name class must be capital. The name of class and name of file are the same. In you case: "student" -> "Student"

Comment: that is definetly not right. you "should" start your class with a upper char, but you can write it as you wish :) The real problem here is, that he wants to create an instance of an inner class. The inner class is not static, therefore the inner class can only exist when the outer class exists, so he has to create both and therefore it is not allowed to create an instance of the inner class. Another solution is to declare the inner calss static, so the binding to the outer class is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I didn't see full code. Anyway, I don't know java class could start with a upper char before. Thanks, I will note it in my mind. :)